# Set view no click focusable in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, view

How can I set view no click focusable in gridview? 
should I do something in "getView" method?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   if (item.isEmpty) {
      convertView.setClickable(false);
      convertView.setFocusable(false);
      convertView.setLongClickable(false);
   }
}
```

Comment: `convertView.setFocusable(true);`  enough.

Comment: I think my convertView has been affected of gridView. Let me check up my widget. Tks